# Setup Github Enterprise server with Azure Active Directory

Tags: git, azure, azure-active-directory, github-enterprise

For some regulation reasons, we have to use our git server on prep. Github.com use to be our main git repo server, now we decided to deploy GitHub Enterprise Server on premise, and we need to link it to AAD.

According to Github, AAD is supported but they do not provide any documentation on that topic (https://help.github.com/en/enterprise/2.18/admin/user-management/using-saml).

When we go to AAD and add the GitHub client application for SAML, we get the following:

> SAML is not enabled for Active Directory for GitHub Enterprise.
>   If the application supports SAML-based single sign-on, you can request Microsoft to upgrade the listing for the application. Learn more 
>   Also, you can use the non-gallery feature to enable SAML-based single sign-on for applications that aren't supported in the Azure AD Gallery.

So, supported and not enabled?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

[SAML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_Assertion_Markup_Language) is an open standard. If it is supported then it will work. You have two options to enable Github and Azure AD integration:

- Azure AD Enterprise Apps Market Place: This is the easiest one, go to Azure Active Directory> Enterprise Applications> New Application> Search and use Github
- Configure the [SAML app manually](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/manage-apps/configure-single-sign-on-non-gallery-applications) into Azure AD.

Comment: Thanks for the links. I already explored that documentation, the GitHub application settings doesn't allow SAML, only GitHub.com allows SAML configuration.

Comment: To be more precise, what would be the Entity ID of my on premise Github? Sign-in URL? Reply URL? I'm missing these parameters as it seem different from the GitHub cloud where the params are https://<url-domain>/orgs/*

Comment: You can get the entity id from github enterprise setup step. See [here](https://learn.akamai.com/en-us/webhelp/enterprise-application-access/enterprise-application-access/GUID-098813E1-5698-42DA-B400-1CF74482A0AD.html) for details.